# Can I make an unchordal MRF equivalent to a chordal MRF?

Tags: probability, bayesian-networks, markov, probability-theory, markov-models

Here BY equivalence I mean, will the distribution(Entire table) be made equal in both cases???

Answer (score 0):

You can always add edges to convert the unchordal MRF to become chordal (but then your factors get bigger).